# How to access overall document count during arithmetic aggregation expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents in this format:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    items: [
        {
            defindex: number,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Certain parts of the schema not relevant are omitted, and each item defindex within the items array is guaranteed to be unique for that array. The same defindex can occur in different documents' `items` fields, but will only occur once in each respective array if present.

I currently call *$unwind* upon the `items` field, followed by *$sortByCount* upon `items.defindex` to get a sorted list of items with the highest count.

I now want to add a new field to this final sorted list using *$set* called `usage`, that shows the item's usage as a percentage of the initial number of total documents in the collection.
(i.e. if the item's `count` is 1300, and the overall document count pre-*$unwind* was 2600, the usage value will be 0.5)

My initial plan was to use *$facet* upon the initial collection, creating a document as so:

```
{
    total: number (achieved using $count),
    documents: [{...}] (achieved using an empty $set)
}
```

And then calling *$unwind* on the documents field to add the total document count to each document. Calculating the usage value is then trivial using *$set*, since the total count is a field in the document itself.

This approach ran into memory issues though, since my collection is far larger than the 16MB limit.

How would I solve this?

Comment: What is "the overall collection size pre-`$unwind`"?  Would you give an example of how that is determined?

Comment: "each item defindex within the items array will only occur once within that array"?  What does this mean?  In the doc's entire `"items"` array, only one object will contain the field `"defindex"`?  Or, each `"defindex"` value is guaranteed to be unique within the array? Perhaps it would be useful to show a full doc and demonstrate the calculations and the desired output.

Comment: @rickhg12hs sorry for being a bit unclear! By "the overall collection size pre-$unwind" I meant the total count of initial documents in the collection, before doing any aggregation. i.e. the result of a $count. And in terms of "defindex" I meant that each value (if present) is guaranteed to be unique within the array. Different documents can contain the same item defindex, but will only have it once in their respective arrays.

Comment: As an aside, I have solved this problem by not using data aggregation pipelines and doing the calculations myself manually using typescript. I'm leaving the question up though, as doing it within the pipeline would be far superior (and seems like it should be quite simple, I just couldn't figure it out!)

Comment: I think starting with: `{ $setWindowFields: { output: { totalCount: {$count: {}}}}}` can work for you

Comment: @nimrodserok that's perfect, thanks so much! If you put that in an answer I'll accept it. I had no idea setWindowFields existed, that helps a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is use `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        totalCount: {$count: {}}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$items.defindex",
      count: {$sum: 1},
      totalCount: {$first: "$totalCount"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: 1,
      usage: {$divide: ["$count", "$totalCount"]
      }
    }
  },
  {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ewu1eGz3E7V)