# I want to write a MongoDB query in NodeJS where it return the matching documents as well as the count of documents too

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to write a MongoDB query in NodeJS where it return the matching documents as well as the count of documents too. For ex consider the below code -

```
const result = await Student.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          ...filter
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          payment: 1,
          type: 1,
          BirthDate: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: { StudentData: -1 }
      },
      {
        $count: 'count'
      },
      {
        $skip: skip
      },
      {
        $limit: limit
      }

    ]
  );
```

Here I want to save two things in the result variable - the number of documents and individually all the documents.

Comment: is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736587/how-to-access-overall-document-count-during-arithmetic-aggregation-expression/71752251#71752251) what you are looking for?

Comment: The `$setWindowFields` is your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let [{ totalItems, result }] = await Student.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          ...filter
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          payment: 1,
          type: 1,
          BirthDate: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $facet: {
          result: [
            {
              $sort: { BirthDate: -1 },
            },
            {
              $skip: skip
            },
            {
              $limit: limit
            }
          ],
          totalItems: [{ $count: 'count' }]
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          totalItems: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$totalItems.count", 0]
          },
        }
      }

    ]
  );
```