# mongodb - get first X results and overall count of aggregate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a aggregate query I'm using to get the 10 first results of a lookup between 2 collections.
I'm only getting the first 10, because if I use no limit and get 50 results the query gets slow (4-5 secs) (any suggestions on that will also be great)

So because Im doing some kind of scan I need to let the client know the number of total results, so it can query more when needed. currently im running the cursor twice and im sure that is not ideal.

```
    const grades = database.collection('grades');
    const match = { userId };
    
    const aggregationPipeline = [
        { $match: match},
        { $addFields: { userIdObj: { $toObjectId: '$userId' } } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'userIdObj',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'userDetails',
            },
        },
    ];
    const aggCursor = grades.aggregate(aggregationPipeline);
    const aggCursorCount = grades.aggregate([...aggregationPipeline, {
        $count: 'count',
    }]);
    const count = await aggCursorCount.toArray();
    const allValues = await aggCursor.limit(10).toArray();
    res.json({grades: allValues, count: count[0].count});
```

Im sure there is a more efficient way to get what I need. Still learning all mongodb stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access overall document count during arithmetic aggregation expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736587/how-to-access-overall-document-count-during-arithmetic-aggregation-expression)

Comment: Since you don't $unwind results of the $lookup the total count of documents will be the save as `grades.countDocuments(match);` It will be the fastest option. As a side note, you can improve performance by adding https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/ stage to your pipeline before the $lookup stage

Comment: @AlexBlex but why does 50 results takes 5 secs?

Comment: To answer the "why" question I will need to look at result of `explain(executionStats)` for both limited and unlimited queries. Without it I can only speculate that unlimited one returns more documents.