# Is there a way to get documents and count of documents in one query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
result = db.collection.find({})
```

This will return us documents of collection.

```
count = db.collection.count_documents({})
```

This will return us count of documents in collection.

I want to get both of documents and count of documents in one query.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access overall document count during arithmetic aggregation expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736587/how-to-access-overall-document-count-during-arithmetic-aggregation-expression)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to use aggregation,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // you can write you query inside $match
    { $match: {} },
    { 
        $facet: {
            // getting total records
            metaData: [{
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    totalCount: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }],
            records: []
        } 
    }
]);
```

Another way of doing it is to use third party module like `mongoose-paginate-v2`, it will provide you all the data with your simple find query.