# Get count of returned documents in $lookup pipeline before $limit - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this $lookup pipeline stage:

```
{ 
  $lookup: {
        'from': 'comments',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'contentId',
        'as': 'comments',
        'pipeline': [{
          '$match': {
            'contentType': 'blog',
            'replyId': null
          }
        }, {
         '$skip': 2
        }, {
         '$limit': 1
        }]
      }
}
```

Is it possible to get the count of documents returned after the $match stage of the $lookup pipeline and projected into my main pipeline (ie the pipeline that $lookup is a part of)?

Thanks

Comment: There are 2 options: `$facet` which you can use to add this data on another key, but this will group your entire '$lookup` pipeline to one document. Other option is to use `$setWindowFields` to add this total count on **each document**, thus providing it to the main pipeline without grouping, but with a need to format.

Comment: For the ` $setWindowFields` option look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736587/how-to-access-overall-document-count-during-arithmetic-aggregation-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `$facet`:

```
{ 
  $lookup: {
        'from': 'comments',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'contentId',
        'as': 'comments',
        'pipeline': [
          {$match: {'contentType': 'blog', 'replyId': null}},
          {$facet: {
            data:[{'$skip': 2}, {'$limit': 1}],
            total:[{$group:{_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}]
          }}]}
}
```

The format is clear, but all the documents you return from the `$lookup` pipeline are grouped to one document under `data`.

The other option is to use `$setWindowFields`:

```
{ 
  $lookup: {
        'from': 'comments',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'contentId',
        'as': 'comments',
        'pipeline': [
          {$match: {'contentType': 'blog', 'replyId': null}},
          {$setWindowFields: {output: {totalCount: {$count: {}}}}}
         ]}
}
```

This will add the `totalCount` to all returned documents, so you need to format it, but the advantage is that your  `$lookup` pipeline results are different documents.